# why does array_intersect_uassoc() compare array keys within the same array?

Tags: php, arrays

Here's an example of using array_intersect_uassoc().

I've deliberately made the keys different, so you can tell which one comes from which array.

```
  $array1 = array("LEFT a" => "green", "LEFT b" => "brown", "LEFT c" => "blue");
  $array2 = array("RIGHT a" => "GREEN", "RIGHT B" => "brown", 'RIGHT y' => "yellow");
  array_intersect_uassoc($array1, $array2, function($a, $b) {
    print_r("$a -- $b");
    return 0;
  });
```

In the output, I see comparisons of two LEFT keys as well as two RIGHT keys.

What on earth is the point of doing this?

Comment: Because if `LEFT a == LEFT b`, you only need to check whether one of those  `== RIGHT a`, but not both. Saves time / is for efficiency. A little now, but on larger arrays this can add up.

Comment: But they're array keys, so no keys in the one array can be equal by definition. And it doesn't matter whether they are < or >, since we're not ordering, we're filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logic code for the function (I simplified it a bit):

```
function array_intersect_uassoc($args, compare_func) 
{
    $result = array();
    $array_count = count($args);
    foreach ($args[0] as $k => $v) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $array_count; $i++) {
            $match = false;
            foreach ($args[$i] as $kk => $vv) {
                $compare = call_user_func_array($compare_func, array($k, $kk));
                if ($compare === 0 && $v == $vv) {
                    $match = true;
                    continue 2;
                }
            }
            if ($match === false) {
                continue 2;
            }
        }

        if ($match === true) {
            $result[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This helps you see that the keys are not the only thing checked, but more importantly the values as well.